# Organize uploads structure in Yii2 advanced template

Tags: yii2

I use Yii2 advanced template. I am curious to how to correctly set uploads structure on server.

What I need:

- Users will upload files on server from frontend. I need to view this
  images in backend.
- At the same time, other users must have no access to uploads folder
  (not able to see images of other users).

How better to store images in such case?

Comment: For that you need to implement RBAC in your application.

Comment: Can you share some useful links where is described how to restrict access to folders using RBAC?

Comment: show this RBAC video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vLb8YATO-HU